# Packages failed to restore during build phase for Bit Framework

Tags: bit-framework

I'm creating my first build definition of a project based on Bit Framework.
I'm getting this error on `Nuget Restore` task on my build definition.

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1101:
Unable to find package BCrypt.Net-Next. 
No packages exist with this id in source(s): Bit

Packages failed to restore
```

How can I restore BCrypt.Net-Next package in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Feeds in my NuGet.config** option in **Feeds and authentication** section. Then choose nuget.config file using file explorer option.

Nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Bit" value="https://www.myget.org/F/bit-foundation/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've done that already. And I selected `src/Nuget.Config`in the path.

Comment: Which agent you use to build your app? Hosted|HostedVS2017?

Comment: It's Hosted VS2017. Do I need any credential?

Comment: BCrypt.Net-Next is not Bit related. And in the NuGet.config just bit's repository is being referenced. Should it have the nugget.org too?

Comment: @mehrandvd Yeah. I've added working sample of nuget.config file.